# For Loop Adder Issues

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create the function described by the parameters below but I keep getting the following as an output value and have not idea why.

Output Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
  File "/Users/<username>/Desktop/CS 1110/lab16/lab16.py", line 66, in 
  letter_grades     
    if result[k] >= 90: 
KeyError: 'wmw2'
```

The dictionary I implemented was `{'wmw2' : 55, 'abc3' : 90, 'jms45': 86})`

```py
def letter_grades(adict):
    """
    Returns: a new dictionary with the letter grades for each student.

    The dictionary adict has netids for keys and numbers 0-100 for values.
    These represent the grades that the students got on the exam.  This function
    returns a new dictionary with netids for keys and letter grades (strings)
    for values.  Our cut-off is 90 for an A, 80 for a B, 70 for a C, 60 for a
    D.  Anything below 60 is an F.

    Example:  letter_grades({'wmw2' : 55, 'abc3' : 90, 'jms45': 86}) evaluates
    to {'wmw2' : 'F, 'abc3' : 'A', 'jms45': 'B'}.

    Parameter adict: the dictionary of grades
    Precondition: alist is a list of ints
    """
    # HINT: You will need a dictionary that acts as an accumulator
    # Start with result = {}.  Then add to this dictionary.
    result = {}
    for k in adict:
        if result[k] >= 90:
            result[k] = 'A'
        elif result[k] >= 80:
            result[k] = 'B'
        elif result[k] >= 70:
            result[k] = 'C'
        elif result[k] >= 60:
            result[k] = 'D'
        else:
            result[k] = 'F'
    return result
```

Comment: `for k in result:` just after you've defined `result` as an empty dict `result = {}`. This for loop is never going to run

Comment: You have to add values to `result` while you're looping through `adict` if you want to return anything other then `{}`

Comment: Instead of `result = {}`, do `result = adict`. Because result does not have any values inside of it, when doing 'result[k]' Python can't access the value for `k` in `result`.

Comment: Making result = adict does work however it modifies the existing dictionary while I seek to create a new one and add to it. That is why i started with ```result = {}``` because I need that to be the new dictionary that I am adding to.

Answer (score 1):

You set

```
`result = {}`
```

So, `result` is empty.
Then you loop over result : `for k in result:`. Thus the loop just has zero element to loop-over. 
Maybe you wanted to write `for k in adict:`

Then, you never assign a value to `result`. Inside your `for loop` you write `adict[k] = ...`.
Maybe you wanted to write `result[k] = ...`

Thus, this gives:

```
result = {}
for k in adict:
    if adict[k] >= 90:
        result[k] = 'A'
    elif adict[k] >= 80:
        result[k] = 'B'
    elif adict[k] >= 70:
        result[k] = 'C'
    elif adict[k] >= 60:
        result[k] = 'D'
    else:
        result[k] = 'F'
return result
```

You want to create a `result` dict according to a `adict` dict. So the condition have to be made on `adict` and the assignment on `result`.

Hope this help you, ask any question.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this before and does not affect anything, I can edit my question to include this.

Comment: I edited my answer to complete it. Was it more accurate now?

Comment: Thank you this helped... unforuntately I did what you said and am now getting ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dilan/Desktop/CS 1110/lab16/lab16.py", line 66, in letter_grades
    if result[k] >= 90:
KeyError: 'wmw2' ``` ( The dictionary I implemented was ```{'wmw2' : 55, 'abc3' : 90, 'jms45': 86}```) I am just confused as to why this is still happening, but thank you for all your help thus far!

Comment: Your dictionary is empty, so you can't look at it. In your ìf` statement you have to look at your `adict` dict, them is the condition is True, you add the item to your `resutl` dict. I will edit my answer to make it more clear